# How to access data from an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm setting up a little script for my personal use to understand Ajax and jQuery by testing the Nike API to have information about any products.

I had done a little loop to have information on the actual API but i'm stuck when i want to pass the seconds objects

```
function getSnkrs() {
    var test = $('.test');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.nike.com/product_feed/threads/v2/?filter=marketplace%28FR%29&filter=language%28fr%29&filter=channelId%28010794e5-35fe-4e32-aaff-cd2c74f89d61%29&&filter=exclusiveAccess%28true%2Cfalse%29",
        async: false,

        success: function(data) {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

                //<br><img src="'+ data._embedded.objects[i].publishedContent[i].nodes[i].properties[i].portraitURL[i].url +'"style="width: 20%; height=auto;><br>
                test.append('<br><a>'+    data.objects[i].publishedContent[y].marketplace   +'</a><br>');

            }
        }
    }
});
```

}

On the console I have this :

> jquery-1.9.1.js:7985 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'marketplace' of undefined
>       at Object.success (script.js:36)
>       at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1148)
>       at done (jquery-1.9.1.js:8074)
>       at callback (jquery-1.9.1.js:8598)
>       at Object.send (jquery-1.9.1.js:8604)
>       at Function.ajax (jquery-1.9.1.js:7978)
>       at getSnkrs (script.js:26)
>       at HTMLDocument. (script.js:3)
>       at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)

I would like to have the element ' marketplace' if someones can help me thank you !  :

```
{
    "pages": {
    "prev": "",
    "next": "/product_feed/threads/v2?filter=marketplace%28FR%29&filter=language%28fr%29&filter=channelId%28010794e5-35fe-4e32-aaff-cd2c74f89d61%29&filter=exclusiveAccess%28true%2Cfalse%29&anchor=50",
    "totalPages": 26,
    "totalResources": 1258
    },
    "objects": [
    {
        "id": "a6ecf9f2-8f73-4d1a-b761-5e0772153fdb",
        "channelId": "010794e5-35fe-4e32-aaff-cd2c74f89d61",
        "channelName": "SNKRS Web",
        "marketplace": "FR",
        "language": "fr",
        "lastFetchTime": "2019-08-13T15:13:15.879Z",
        "publishedContent": {
        "preview": false,
        "marketplace": "FR",
```

Comment: `publishedContent` is not an array. Try `test.append('<br><a>'+ data.objects[i].publishedContent.marketplace   +'</a><br>');`. I guess you can also remove the inner loop.

Comment: Also, I would not recommend using `async:false`

Comment: Remove the loops and try `data.objects.forEach(obj => test.append('<br><a>'  + obj.publishedContent.marketplace + '</a><br>'))` instead.

Comment: As per the question asked ur sample json doesn't have publishedContent as array so it will give error.

Comment: Wow thank you so much ! @Nope

Comment: @skez You're welcome. Please mark Fajar AMs answer as the accepted one.  So he gets a few points for his effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i saw that publisherContent is not an array? (correct me if i m wrong), it is a json object. try to remove the "y" looping:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.objects.length; i++) {

//<br><img src="'+ data._embedded.objects[i].publishedContent[i].nodes[i].properties[i].portraitURL[i].url +'"style="width: 20%; height=auto;><br>
test.append('<br><a>'+ data.objects[i].publishedContent.marketplace   +'</a><br>');
}
```

Comment: Can you change `i = 0` to `var i = 0`? You could also mention, that it would be clever to use `for (var i = 0; i < data.objects.length; i++) {` and explain why.

Comment: thanks for the correction. i only copied and pasted the code -without paying attention to the syntax- from the question then removed unused part. that s it. It is possible that var i might had been declarated somewhere inside the code ...

Comment: @FajarAM You're totally right! But skez is obviously a beginner and he needed some support. And I didn't want to write an answer if there is already a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer without jQuery, just plain JS:

```js
const marketplacesEl = document.getElementById("marketplaces");

fetch(
  "https://api.nike.com/product_feed/threads/v2/?filter=marketplace%28FR%29&filter=language%28fr%29&filter=channelId%28010794e5-35fe-4e32-aaff-cd2c74f89d61%29&&filter=exclusiveAccess%28true%2Cfalse%29"
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(({ objects }) =>
    objects.forEach(
      ({ publishedContent: { marketplace } }) =>
        (marketplacesEl.appendChild(
          document.createElement("li")
        ).innerHTML = marketplace)
    )
  );
```

```html
<ul id="marketplaces"></ul>
```